# Windows program uses incorrect (bold) font

Tags: windows, fonts

I have program running on windows 10 which refuses to use correct font. I could only find 3 similar cases on entire web and solutions provided are not helpful, which is driving me nuts.
It appears the program in question goes to a bold fallback font which leads to text not fitting.
This only happens on my win10 **workstation machine**, on other machines the program font displays fine.

[image: wrong program font]

[image: correct program font font]

I traced it back to "MS Sans Serif" SSERIFER.FON and SSERIFFR.FON fonts.
If registry delete these system fonts on machine where program displays correctly i recreate the same result as on my workstation machine. Reinstalling these fonts on my workstation doesn't fix the issue!

Things i have tried so far:

1. Windows feature to restore fonts
2. Installing fonts myself. However, reinstalled fonts go into the user font folder, and my problem is the system font.
3. Using registry script to restore Segoe UI fonts.
4. Clearing font cache.
5. Reinstalling GPU drivers.
6. Installing program with fresh user profile, in case it was corrupted.
7. Reinstalling .NET framework. Program requires net framework 4.0 and faults back to bold font directly in Installshield.

I could reinstall OS, but its truly a last resort for me.

Comment: Have you tried using the checkbox for "Use Windows Fonts" ?

Comment: What kind of program is it? Does it date from before Windows 10? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Use windows fonts is the font settings for the Text box.
It's HMI editing software which works on any win 7/10/11 machine i tried, except my main win10 machine.

Comment: Is this problem systemwide or only something with this specific problem? If the latter, there may be a setting in the program itself that was changed to cause this.

Comment: I do notice that the windows GUI part is different between screenshots too. Is the affected system using High Contrast theme? If so, disable these accessibility options, and see if it goes away.

Comment: So it's a quite old program. Try : Find its `.exe` file, right-click it and select Properties. In the Compatibility tab click "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and select "Windows 7". Click OK and try to run the program.

Comment: @LPChip I have a normal theme. It looks like this because the font somehow affects the dialog box itself. Here is a old thread with similar problem, though it dint help me:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/font-size-too-big-for-some-programs/d9d59c46-dc1e-44a5-b2ef-be1b4534cc72

Comment: @harrymc Tried Compatibility tab, and also played some with DPI settings, no effect.

Comment: Perhaps Windows 10 is too different now from Windows 7. You might need to use a virtual machine with Windows 7, if you can't stand these fonts.